# How to tell what template C++ generated

Tags: c++, templates

I have a C++ template function that looks like

```
template <class T>
void Item::SetValue(T value){
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << value;
    this->value = oss.str();
}
```

It's been working fine for *years* until today when my OS (vxworks) threw an SPE exception at me. This basically means I was trying to do floating point arithmetic in a task context that doesn't allow it. This would be fine if I was indeed doing any floating point stuff, but I in fact am just passing a `uint32_t` to this function. However there are 100s of calls to this function elsewhere from other modules, so who knows what C++ has generated.

I need to know for sure this is the problem (I'm 99% sure) so I want to know if there's any way for me to figure out what function C++ compiler generated for that call. Is there any way?

---

I may have to ask a new question. I found in the debugger that it is using `Item::SetValue<unsigned int>` and that it is actually throwing the exception in `std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char>>>::do_put` (at least, i think). This is the instruction output, and it is failing in `evstdd` which is definitely in the SPE set. Still don't know why it wants to do any floating point stuff.

Is it possible that

`oss << value`

Will always treat `value` as a float, just in case? IE in `std::num_put`? I don't know how I'll get around this.

[Instruction set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvuDN.png)

Comment: `for that call` Which call do you mean? Yours with the `uint32_t` or one of the hundreds of others with (presumably) a floating point argument somewhere?

Comment: `C++ compiler generated for that call`? use debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `type_traits`

```
if(std::is_same_v(T, uint32_t)) { /*debug info*/ }
```

Comment: also you can use `is_floating_point` `is_integral` and so on

Comment: Ehm, as `evstdd` is just load/store OP, so it can be used for any types if compiler thinks it's faster

Comment: Looks like I'll just have to force that task to be SPE compatible.

Answer (score 3):

The classical solution is to add to the body of the function:

```
static_assert(!std::is_floating_point_v<T>);
```